# ModernWPFUI NugetPackage 'ThemeResources/XamlControlsResources' does not exist in the current context/NuGet package cannot be found

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, nuget

I'm working on a school assignment which contains a NuGet package called 'ModernWPFUI'. In order to implement the components, I need to reference ui:ThemeResources and ui:XamlControlsResources. This was code that I'm just returning to over a month or two, so I am worried something has broken. My whole project is built upon the 'ModernWPFUI' NuGet package so it's vital that no errors are found.

The problem is, when building, I get the following output:

[image]

EVEN when it shows in the designer:

[image]

ui:ThemeResources is also displayed in the designer (intellisense). I'm just wondering what's going on here? I've tried to **clean, rebuild, build, and go back to earlier versions but nothing has fixed this**.

This my app.xaml page which contains all of my styling. Notice at the top the references:

```
<Application x:Class="SimonWPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimonWPF"
             StartupUri="Folder Library/Pages/SimonHome.xaml"
             xmlns:ui="http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ui:ThemeResources />
                <ui:XamlControlsResources />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate1"
                             TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid />
            </ControlTemplate>

            <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Rectangle Margin="2"
                                       SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                       Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                                       StrokeThickness="1"
                                       StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background"
                             Color="#FFDDDDDD" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border"
                             Color="#FF707070" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background"
                             Color="#FFBEE6FD" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border"
                             Color="#FF3C7FB1" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background"
                             Color="#FFC4E5F6" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border"
                             Color="#FF2C628B" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background"
                             Color="#FFF4F4F4" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border"
                             Color="#FFADB2B5" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground"
                             Color="#FF838383" />
            <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1"
                   TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                        Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}" />
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="border"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                  Focusable="False"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted"
                                         Value="true">
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                         Value="true">


                                </Trigger>

                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                         Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Background"
                                            TargetName="border"
                                            Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                            TargetName="border"
                                            Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                                            TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                            Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <!--Button styling-->
            <Style TargetType="Button"
                   x:Key="HoverStyle"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}">
                
                <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                            Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                            Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding"
                            Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border x:Name="border"
                                        BorderBrush="White"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                      Focusable="False"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted"
                                         Value="true">
                
                                </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                             Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                            Value="2" />
                                </Trigger>
                              
                                 

                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                             Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                                TargetName="border"
                                                Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}" />
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                                TargetName="border"
                                                Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}" />
                                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                                                TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                                Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>

            <!--Button styling-->
            <Style TargetType="Button"
                   x:Key="YesOrNo_Style"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource HoverStyle}">

                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="18.55" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                        Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="#29ABE2" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="Segoe UI Light" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="Window"
                   x:Key="DefaultWindowDialogueStyle">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="WindowStyle"
                        Value="None" />
                <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency"
                        Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="ResizeMode"
                        Value="NoResize" />
            </Style>





            <!--Border dialogue style-->
            <Style TargetType="Border"
                   x:Key="DefaultBorderDialogueStyle">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="LightBlue" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15"
                                          ShadowDepth="0"
                                          Opacity="0.6"
                                          Color="Black" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <!--Dialogue rectangle style-->
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle"
                   x:Key="DialogueRectangleBaseStyle">
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness"
                        Value="0" />
            </Style>

            <!--Dialogue rectangle style title-->
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogueRectangleBaseStyle}"
                   x:Key="DialogueRectangleTitleStyle">
                <Setter Property="Fill"
                        Value="#29ABE2" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                        Value="0" />
            </Style>

            <!--Dialogue rectangle content title-->
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogueRectangleBaseStyle}"
                   x:Key="DialogueRectangleContentStyle">
                <Setter Property="Fill"
                        Value="#29BDE2" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                        Value="1" />
            </Style>

            <!--Dialogue rectangle footer title-->
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogueRectangleBaseStyle}"
                   x:Key="DialogueRectangleFooterStyle">
                <Setter Property="Fill"
                        Value="#0095BC" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                        Value="2" />
            </Style>

            <!--Dialogue text icon style-->
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
                   x:Key="DialogueTextIconStyle">
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="0,0,52,0" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                        Value="Right" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="43" />
            </Style>

            <!--Dialogue text title style-->
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogueTextIconStyle}"
                   x:Key="DialogueTextTitleStyle">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="Segoe UI Light" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                        Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="52,0,0,0" />
            </Style>
            
            <!--Dialogue text title style *game over-->
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogueTextTitleStyle}"
                   x:Key="DialogueTextTileStyleCenter">
                <Setter Property="Text"
                        Value="Game Over!" />
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
                   x:Key="GameOverDialogueShortDescriptionStyle">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="40,20" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="33" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="Segoe UI Semibold" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                        Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="LineHeight"
                        Value="40" />
            </Style>
                   
            <!--Dialogue text paragraph style-->
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
                   x:Key="DialogueTextParagraphStyle">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="Segoe UI Semilight" />
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="40,20" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="22" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="LineHeight"
                        Value="35" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                        Value="1" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="Button"
                   x:Key="DialogueExitButtonStyle"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource YesOrNo_Style}">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                        Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                        Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="25" />
                <Setter Property="Content"
                        Value="Exit" />

            </Style>



            <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
                   x:Key="AchievementTitle_Style">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="42" />
                <Setter Property="LineHeight"
                        Value="38" />
                <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy"
                        Value="BlockLineHeight" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                        Value="Top" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
                   x:Key="AchievementSubtitle_Style"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource AchievementTitle_Style}">
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="24.95" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="Segoe UI Light" />
                <Setter Property="Margin"
                        Value="0,0,0,-10" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                        Value="2" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="Run"
                   x:Key="DefaultRun_Style">
                <Setter Property="FontSize"
                        Value="24.95" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                        Value="Segoe UI Light" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="Viewbox"
                   x:Key="DefaultViewbox_Style">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                        Value="Left" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
      
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I've come across a spoonfull of errors with this NuGet package and this is one I've been trying to fix for a long time. I don't understand why it can't find/reference the ui:ThemeResources and the ui:XamlControlsResources.

Thank you,

**EDIT: I'm also getting this following output**
[image]

What do you suggest I do?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Try to delete the hidden `.vs` folder and clear the NuGet caches via _Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Clear all NuGet Caches_. Does that work? Which version of the package do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This started happening to me at completely random times and I realized it was because the schema website - http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019 - keeps going down. This is only solvable by the project maintainer, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It looks like the website redirects to his github page. Maybe it was unintentional?